# how to load the video data from url for 2 seconds only, to Play video for the first 2 seconds only

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

I wants to play videos for the first 2 seconds only (recyclerView). So for the better memory management i want to stream video of max 2 seconds from given online url.

below code plays video immediately but it loads the whole video.

```
try {
     TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
     DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder().setBufferDurationsMs(32 * 1024, 64 * 1024, 1024, 1024).createDefaultLoadControl();
     exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
     //exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

     Uri videouri = Uri.parse("https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/vidos/d293c6d7-8b2d-436a-998d-a454476485a4.mp4");
     DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");

     ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
     MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videouri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
     exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
     exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
     exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      logAppE(TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set maximum buffer size to limit what part of video is loaded.

[Check out this article](https://www.akamai.com/blog/performance/enhancing-video-streaming-quality-for-exoplayer-part-2-exoplayers-buffering-strategy-how-to-lower)